# How do I use Wasm in the content script of a Firefox web extension?

Tags: javascript, rust, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, webassembly

I am building a Firefox addon using Rust. I am trying to insert HTML and do stuff on specific pages. Apparently, a content script is the thing I want to use. My content script is:

```js
import("../crate/pkg").then(({ Addon }) => {
    const addon = Addon.new();

    console.log(addon.where_am_i());
}).catch(e => console.error("Error importing:", e));
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: "0125c9960050e7483877.module.wasm is not a valid URL."
```

I tried to add to `manifest.json`:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "0125c9960050e7483877.module.wasm"
]
```

I accessed it as `moz-extension://<extension-UUID>/0125c9960050e7483877.module.wasm"` but then I got:

```
Error importing: Error: "Loading chunk 0 failed.
```

I also tried a background script, but that is loaded in extension context so it doesn't allow me to alter page content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how `import("../crate/pkg")` works at all for you, as [dynamic module imports are not supported in content scripts in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1536094) and "../crate/pkg" doesn't look like a path that can work. Perhaps you're doing some preprocessing?

Loading bare WASM (I took add.wasm from [this sample](https://www.hellorust.com/demos/add/index.html)) works fine if you have `"web_accessible_resources": ["add.wasm"]` in your manifest.json:

```
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(browser.runtime.getURL("add.wasm")), {})
.then(results => {
  console.log("wasm returned", results.instance.exports.add_one(41));
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error("Unable to instantiateStreaming", err)
});
```

Getting a generated JS wrapper to work in content script is a different question, which depends on the tooling and the specific mode you run in.

If you are able to run WASM in a background script, you can [communicate between the content script and the background script via sendMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts) to get the job done.